# Asp.Net MVC 3: Compare validator on subproperties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

For the edition of my user, I've to ensure that password and the repeat password are the same. I found the "Compare" validator, but I cant make it work.

my model looks like the following:

```
public class UserEditionViewModel{
   [Compare("User.Password")]
   public String RepeatPassword{get;set;}

   public User User {get;set;}
   public List<Language> AvailableLanguages{get;set;}
   public List<Country> AvailableCountries{get;set;}
}
```

and the User model:

```
public class User{
   [Required]
   public String Name{get;set;}

   //lot of other properties omitted...

   [RegularExpression(@"(|.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*)", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LocalizationResources.Views.User.Edition), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidPassword")]
   //And I've localization attributes
   public String Password{get;set;}
}
```

In the view I only have something like:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.User.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.RepeatPassword)
```

But I ever get this error, even if the two items are matching:

```
'Password repeat' and 'User.Password' do not match.
```

I also got this error when I'm doing the client validation.

For me the most obvious error is that it can't found the subproperty. Am I right? If yes, how to avoid this behavior. If no, what can be the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to create another property on the `UserEditionViewModel` that reads and writes to the inner `User`class.

```
public String UserPassword 
{
    get
    {
        return User.Password;
    }
    set
    {
        User.Password = value;
    }
}
```

And then bind your controls to that property instead, and change the `[Compare("User.Password")]` to `[Compare("UserPassword")]`. I'm not really sure if it can be done any other way short of writing your own custom validator.

I had a similar problem and ended up writing my own validator for this which turned out surprisingly complex since you can have any layer of inheritance to get to your property. If there is another solution, I'd be equally happy to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which worked for me..

1. In your project -> References-> right click->Manage NuGet Packages..
2. install DataAnnotationsExtensions package.
3. Then validate  your model as follows:

   public class Employee
   {
       [Required(ErrorMessage="Name field Required")]

   ```
   public string name { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name field Required")]
   public string email { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Depatrment field Required")]
   public string department { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Designation field Required")]
   public string designation { get; set; }
   public string  phone { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password field Required")]
   [Display(Name="Password")]
   public string password { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Confirm password")]
   [Display(Name="Re-type Password")]
   [EqualToAttribute("password",ErrorMessage="Password miss-match")]
   public string Re_Password { get; set; }
   ```

   }

That's it